# What are the allowed ways to close self-closing tags for void elements such as <br> in HTML5?

Tags: html

In HTML5 is it still appropriate to close a `<br>` tag with `<br />`?

This obviously also applies to all other single tags. I realize this doesn't actually affect how stuff works, but what is best practice here?

```html
someLines of txt <br>            // How you see a lot of people doing it
and then some <br />             // XHTML style! Should I still be doing this? 
ow im not done yet.. <br> </br>  // No one does this right? RIGHT?!
```

Comment: What does the [HTML Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) tell you?

Comment: Between `<br>` and `<br/>` doesn't matter really, that said with `<br/>` you're sending an extra character that is ignored by the browser. So why bother using the bandwidth? It all adds up.

Comment: @Greg Not true, see my comment below the accepted answer. As for bandwidth – use gzipped content and try if you can see the difference. Or do you happen to work for Google or Amazon, where the single-bit difference actually matters?

Comment: @Brad — The W3C validator is not ready for HTML5. In validating a direct input, the option *Validate HTML fragment* has only these two choices : *HTML 4.01*, *XHTML 1.0*. This may be a good thing. ;-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the [W3C specification for HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element):

- The following is a complete list of the void elements in HTML:

  - `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `command`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `keygen`, `link`, `meta`, `param`, `source`, `track`, `wbr`
- Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.
- Start tags consist of the following parts, in exactly the following order:

  - A `<` character.
  - The element’s tag name.
  - Optionally, one or more attributes, each of which must be preceded by one or more space characters.
  - Optionally, one or more space characters.
  - Optionally, a `/` character, which may be present only if the element is a void element.
  - A `>` character.

From this it seems that we can use either `<br>` or `<br/>`. However, the end tag `</br>` is **not** valid, so don't use `<br> </br>`.

Running the following through the [HTML Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) indicates as much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing void elements</title>
</head>
<body>
    some lines of txt <br>
    and then some more <br />
    I'm not done yet... <br> </br> <!-- This line generates an error -->
</body>
</html>
```

So use either `<br>` or `<br/>`, just make sure you use them consistently.

**Edit**: As noted by Brad, `<br />` is also valid XHTML, so perhaps it is best to choose this form.

Comment: Just curious as to why being valid XML would be an advantage?

Comment: I should have said valid XHTML. Some people like to be extra strict. I have Updated my answer to  XTML, rather than XML.

Comment: @Greg Because then you can use a stricter parser to tell you whether your markup is valid. I can’t count how often I’ve been bitten by valid, but logically wrong HTML markup due to wrong nesting or similar things, which an XML validator would have told me about. My last project iN HTML5 used HTML instead of XHTML, and it will be my last. Frigging waste of time – much more than writing some extra characters for self-closing tags.

Comment: I agree with @Konrad. That's why my answer mentioned "*better tool support*" when using XHTML/XML

Comment: Chris, the W3C validator is not ready for HTML5. In validating a direct input, the option Validate HTML fragment has only these two choices : HTML 4.01, XHTML 1.0. This may be a good thing. ;-)

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco It is ready for HTML5. When validating the code markup I posted in my answer I get an error message "Error found while checking this document as **HTML5**!". In fact, the drop-down list of doctypes contains about 26 options, so there are more than the two choices you state. However, the W3C validation service warns that the HTML5 Conformance Checker is *an experimental feature*. So it is ready for HTML5, but HTML5 itself may change and the validator may not match the very latest standard. If you notice that it does not, [then report it](http://validator.w3.org/feedback.html)

Answer (score 6):

IMHO I think its best to adhere to XHTML standards, even closing the so-called `void` elements as noted by @Alex. If your code is also valid XML then you *may* find better tool support for managing your code

```
<br>  // not valid XML without a closing tag

<br /> // valid XML and I prefer this

<br></br>  // valid XML but unnecessary clutter
```

In anycase if you should run your code through the [HTML Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/). As long as it's valid you're then only dealing with coding style, of which everyone will have their own personal slant on the issue.

**[EDIT]**

To clarify my answer, I suggest the use of either of these `XHTML` headers...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

If you're coding for HTML5 then the clients/browsers should support the strict standard

Comment: `<br> </br>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: If you use `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` it will validate `<br> </br>`. You are correct that is does not validate using `HTML`

Answer (score 3):

It is more important that you are consistent, if you use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` then tags that are void or self closing as some say, will be handled for you by the parser.

Decide on one approach and stick to it, we decided to go with xhtml style syntax but we don't acutally use xhtml. Even though the parser is more lenient its other people that need to be able to understand your markup, so if you have a standard and everyone buys in to this, then everyone is singing from the same hymn sheet.

Why do we need conventions? Because all the following are valid:

```
<META CHARSET=UTF-8>        
<META CHARSET=UTF-8 />      
<META CHARSET="UTF-8">      
<META CHARSET="UTF-8" />        
<meta charset=utf-8>        
<meta charset=utf-8 />      
<meta charset="utf-8">      
<meta charset="utf-8" />        
<MeTa CHARset=utF-8>
```

Another thing to think about is html5 attributes, we decided to use the boolean style attributes at the end of a set of attributes and always use quotes around the others eg:

```
<video id=“vid1” data-someting="my_val" controls>
```

This way we don't have to use the redundant syntax (in my opinion):

```
<video id=“vid1” controls="controls">
```

Just because html5 lets us leave out closing tags, even the `</p>` tag, it doesn't make it right.

I hope that you decide to go with xhtml 'sytle' syntax for your own sanity!

Comment: My own sanity is aided by simplicity. Simplicity does not always imply lack of rigor. This is seen often in mathematics and physics. I think the advent of HTML5 is an excellent time to begin (or continue) simplifying all textual aspects of website specification. An example is specifying a paragraph as TEXT<p> instead of <p>TEXT</p>. Let's enclose text in a block only when when we really need a block (either to move it around the page, or to manipulate it with JS). A <p> should be not so much a semantic paragraph as visual space after/before visual elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `/` is valid & ignored in html 5 for [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element), of which `br` is one, so its entirely up to you although personally I would get out of the habit as its a legacy thing. (The fact its a void element means that as you say; `<br> </br>` is nonsensical)

Comment: According to the specification you link to: "Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements", so I guess the answer is to use `<br>` or `<br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

After learning about self-closing tags from the linked article I came to know that `<br>`, `<br/>` or `<br />` all are valid in HTML5.

But if you write `<br/>` or `<br />` then they will eventually be converted to `<br>` in HTML5 by browsers.

Also if you write `<br></br>` they browser will not generate some error but it will read it as 2 `<br>` tags.

```
someLines of txt <br>            // This is completly valid and recommended
and then some <br />             // XHTML style! should be written like this in XHTML but in HTML5 you can just write <br>
ow im not done yet.. <br> </br>  // Even if you do this then no error will generate. Instead browser will read it as 2 <br> tags
```

Here is how:

```
<p>This is paragraph with &lt;br&gt;<br> and &lt;br/&gt;<br/> and then &lt;br /&gt;<br />.</p>
<p>closing br is wrong way <br></br> but browser read it as 2 br.</p>
```

How it looks in the browser:

[image]