# what's the correct way to end an empty tag in HTML5 today

Tags: html

How do I end tags such as `link` or `input` in **HTML5**.

This

```
<input type='text' size='10'>
```

or this

```
<input type='text' size='10'/>
```

> **Duplicate with more explanation**
>
> [Closing tags in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598501/closing-tags-in-html5)

**Conclusion:** ***You can use either.***

Comment: A similar question was discussed a couple of days ago, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10599002/623518. I would say `<input type='text' size='10' />`.

Comment: Basically, both of the options you list are valid HTML5 (see the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element)). However, `<input type='text' size='10' />` is also valid XHTML.

Comment: @Chris: So are you saying there are **three**? one without `/`, second with `/>` and third `/>` with a leading space?

Comment: Yes. In the HTML5 specification (I really recommend you read it) you can have any number of spaces between the tag and attributes and the closing `>`. Also, with *void* elements, like `<input>`, you can optionally have a `/` immediately before the closing `>`.

Comment: But do you really think supporting XHTML is important? I mean now that we're sure to have HTML 5 as future and XHTML as the dead end. BTW thanks for the link to the other question.

Comment: Generally it is not that important, but XHTML is definitely not obsolete. We could have a very long discussion about why you should care about XHTML (search on this site, there is a lot of enlightening discussion). One quick reason is that there is such a thing as XHTML5, which is the XML serialisation of HTML5, which is often useful to use for automatically generating HTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

The method in the recommendation is:

```
<input type='text' size='10'>
```

Comment: As far as I know that's correct. You could also look at solutions like HTML5Shim to bring older versions of IE into line...

Comment: The discussion surrounding [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10598501/623518) came to the consensus that `<input type='text' size='10' />` was preferable since it is also valid XHTML. @good_computer No IE won't have a problem with this form.

Comment: But don't you think XHTML is dead -- I mean kind of dead -- because of HTML 5? (I might be wrong here, please correct me if I am). But I think if XHTML is indeed obsolete, why support it?

Comment: @Chris - sure it's also valid xhtml, but if you've specified <!DOCTYPE html> in your document you're not using xhtml anyway, and thus there's no need for it to validate as xhtml.

Comment: @good_computer It's about using the correct tool for the job. HTML5 is - and pretty much always has been - about presenting data in browsers. XHTML is more strict and as such as well-suited to data presentation and delivering content to mobile devices. However as the line between desktop and mobile browsing continues to blur I imagine we'll see a lot more crossover between the two.

Comment: @Nealio Agreed, but it is a lot easier to change your doctype than all of your closing tags.