# why does this div leave a margin at the bottom

Tags: layout, html, css

I am currently in learning CSS and it seems I have a hard time understanding the box model. I have a very simple page layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simpleimagebrowser.css">
</head>
<body>
<menu type="toolbar">
    <ul>
        <li>prev</li>
        <li>next</li>
    </ul>
</menu>
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="images/awsome.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and a very simple css:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
menu
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: green;
}
ul
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li
{
    display: inline;
}
img
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.imagecontainer
{
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Why is does my yellow `<div>` have this little margin or gap at the bottom?**

I noticed that when I set the `font-size` to `0` that margin goes away. Can someone explain conceptually what's going on from a css/boxmodel perspective? It seems as if the browser is adding a blank text line below the image or something ...

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it but you didn't close your img tag. It should be self closing with /> at the end of it.

Comment: I think in html5 land this is not necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598501/closing-tags-in-html5

Comment: Have you tried setting you body or that image container ( whatever contains that yellow ) height to 100% ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612380/get-rid-of-space-underneath-inline-block-image I am not asking how to get rid of it (as I mentioned, I already now a solution), I am asking for an explanation why this happens:

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: block;` to your image

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

The white space is due to the image being an `inline` element. I suppose it's the equivalent of `line-height`which adds white space around text.

Comment: Yeah, but why is there an extra space under an inline element ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because all inline elements are expected to fit the 'contains text' model of a span tag, where space is reserved for the tails on letters like g, q, j, etc.

If non, this extra-space is used for 'link underlining' by default browser settings on inline level elements. Meaning, it reserves space for a link hover underline.

**tail (n: tel)**

> Of a letter, the part that extends below the baseline and to the
>   right, as gjqy. Of the capital letters, Q and R have tails, though
>   they need not extend below the baseline.

Comment: Is there a special CSS property for this "link underlining", so I could turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, adding "display: block;" to your img rule will make the problem go away.  This is most likely due to images being treated as "inline" or "inline-block" by default.  Thus the browser is very likely attempting to work your image into the line-height of the parent element.

Comment: You took too long for accepting modifications, i posted the answer myself.