# How to .append text to a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to append a piece of text to a div using jQuery. I try to do this using the following code:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sendButton").click(function(){
            $("#conversation").append("<P>This is a message");
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="conversation"><p>some message</div>
<form><input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message"></form>
</body></html>
```

Seeing the multitude of tutorials on the subject it seems to be such a simple thing to do, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't append partial elements, and you shouldn't have unclosed elements in your HTML either ? Others will soon point out that the selector is wrong as well.

Comment: @adeneo: [The p element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element): _A p element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element_ And the `<input>` element is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) which doesn't need an end tag (and the `/` is optional)

Comment: @Andreas - That's why I wrote "shouldn't", as you can omit the closing P tag, but in javascript you simply can't, jQuery fixes this and uses innerHTML, createElement, appendChild internally (depending on the method), and in javascript there's no such thing as an unclosed element, with the exception of self closing elements, so appending half an element is just plain wrong, even if the parser inserts the closing P tag for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), As `#conversation` referes to element with id conversation

```
 $(".conversation").append("<P>aergerag");
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/KQTMr/)

### EDIT

You should look at this [To Close or Not To Close Tags in HTML5](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/to-close-or-not-to-close-tags-in-html5) and a good question  [Closing tags in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598501/closing-tags-in-html5)

Answer (score 3):

replace `#` with `.` in your selector  (*conversation is a [CLASS](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)*)

```
$(".conversation").append("<P>aergerag");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not any good at jQuery but from one of my projects I had to simply target the div with html as:
 
`var someData = "This is a message";
$("#conversation").html(someData);`

If some contents exists before this, then you can retrieve them, concatenate, and write it back into the target div.